# mandar el valor de una variable en python a otra funcion en otro archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera saber que es lo que me esta fallando con el siguinte codigo, ya que trato de mandar el valor de la variable(result) a una funcion dentro de otro archivo.

este es el codigo :

```
from ticket import *
def vender_data(self):
    acount1 = 0 #cantidad de ibjetos
    venta = list()
    result =0 #resultado total
    Ticket().total(result)
    if acount1 == 0:
        s =self.tabla.rowCount()
        for i in range(0,s):
        #   print(self.tabla.item(i,3).text())
            v = float(self.tabla.item(i,3).text())
            venta.append(v)
        for vs in venta:
            result = result+vs
        print(result) # este funciona 
        acount1 = s
        #print(acount1) total de productos
    elif acount1 !=0:
        venta.clear()
        s = self.tabla.rowCount() - acount1
        for i in range(0,s):
        #   print(self.tabla.item(i,3).text())
            v1 = float(self.tabla.item(i,3).text())
            venta.append(v1)
        for vs in venta:
            result = result+vs
        #print(result)
        acount1 = s

    Ticket().exec_()
```

y este el archivo donde debe de llegar el valor de la variable:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic



class Ticket(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("ticket.ui",self)


    def total(self,total1):
        n = total1
        self.l_total.setText(str(n)) #lineEdit que recive el valor
```

Sin embargo no funciona
Que estoy haciendo mal¿?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer como OOP funciona, un programa funcionalmente no es un conjunto de archivos, en un conjunto de objetos que interactuan por lo que le pregunta cual es el main de su proyecto, a quien pertenece vender_data(), etc, provea un [mcve]. Las clases son como fábricas, solo definen el comportamiento, solo son abstracciones, los objetos son elementos concretos en tu caso Ticket().total(result) es un objeto diferente a Ticket().exec_()

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara y el ejemplo de código no ayuda a clarificarlo, pero sospecho que tu problema está en que usas `Ticket()` para instanciar un objeto `Ticket` y seguidamente llamar a un método dentro de él. Cada vez que haces eso creas un objeto nuevo, independiente del anterior. Prueba a crear uno solo con: `ticket=Ticket()` y después usar ese dentro del código para llamar a sus métodos `ticket.total(result)` y `ticket._exec()`.

Comment: @abulafia. Gracias eso era lo que necesitaba